Pandas resample dataframe based on one column but selecting corresponding row from other columns
I have a dataframe like the one below (just showing the first few rows for the example).
I want to resample the dataframe using the maximum of the 'Depth' column for every 24h, and selecting the rows associated with that maximum depth value.
                   Time  Depth  Temperature 
0  20:15:45 08-Aug-2022   15.5        15.15
1  20:15:50 08-Aug-2022   19.0        13.15 
2  20:15:55 08-Aug-2022   24.5        10.85 
3  20:16:00 08-Aug-2022   30.0         8.00
4  20:16:05 08-Aug-2022   35.5         7.25



When using this code, it sample the max for each column:
tag_data2 = tag_data.resample('24h').max('Depth')

And gives me this output:
           Depth  Temperature
Time                                                                     
2022-08-08   35.5         15.15

but I would like the output to be:
           Depth  Temperature
Time                                                                     
2022-08-08   35.5         7.25


You should use resample.idxmax:
out = tag_data.loc[tag_data.resample('24h')['Depth'].idxmax()]

Output:
                     Depth  Temperature
Time                                   
2022-08-08 20:16:05   35.5         7.25

And if you want to update the index:
idx = tag_data.resample('24h')['Depth'].idxmax()

out = tag_data.loc[idx].set_axis(idx.index)

Output:
            Depth  Temperature
Time                          
2022-08-08   35.5         7.25

Or:
out = (tag_data
       .resample('24h')['Depth'].idxmax().to_frame(name='max_time')
       .merge(tag_data, left_on='max_time', right_index=True)
      )

Output:
                      max_time  Depth  Temperature
Time                                              
2022-08-08 2022-08-08 20:16:05   35.5         7.25

